# How to use paypal API to allow customers to draw down funds owed to them

Tags: paypal, payment

I am building a site for a client that involves incentivising users to perform a service in the site by paying them. I'm a beginner with the paypal API and so am looking for the best way to do this.

I don't need the payment to be made in real time - i.e. paid to them as soon as they carry out the service (although this would be good if there's a straightforward way to do it).

My plan is to have a 'total owed' value in the database for the user that is incremented every time they perform the service. I want to allow these users to 'draw down' those funds from my client's paypal business account when they choose to, ideally by their supplying their paypal account email address only.

Can anyone give me any tips about the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks!